# Raspberry pi Google cast

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-cast

Hi I have a Google home but it will only cast to a Google cast device is there any way to use the Google cast SDK so I can cast videos to my raspberry pi

Comment: Try to check the documentation about [Receiver Applications](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps). There are two types of implementation, [Styled Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#Styled) and [Custom Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#Custom).

Comment: Any luck on implementing Receiver for Pi @a-bea?